# gitlab ci error could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name does not resolve

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I use gitlab-ci in my rails app, it ran correctly till yesterday
but it does not pass due to:

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name does not resolve
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
....
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load => db:check_protected_environments
```

.gitlab-ci.yml :

```
rspec:
  stage: test
  services:
    - postgres:10
  variables:
    DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/$POSTGRES_DB"
    POSTGRES_DB: db_test
    RAILS_ENV: test
  before_script:
    - ruby -v
  script:
    - cp config/application.sample.yml config/application.yml
    - cp config/database.sample.yml config/database.yml
    - bundle exec rake db:schema:load
    - bundle exec rspec spec
```

It seems it can not find the postgres service running or for some reason the database service is not running correctly, I guess some internals has changed in gitlab-ci.

Comment: Experiencing same issue with django app as well. Definitely something internal changed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDIT: This was an intended change to the images, [you now must set a password or configure further:](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/681#issuecomment-586517154)

> If you know that you want to be insecure (i.e. any one can connect without a password from anywhere), then POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust is how you opt in to that.

---

This seems to have been introduced when the docker images were upgraded to the [new releases](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/2011/).

You can pull the 10.11 image instead to avoid this problem for the time being:

```
services:
- postgres:10.11
```

Not sure why this is happening, but we are experiencing the same since the [last docker image update](https://hub.docker.com/layers/postgres/library/postgres/10/images/sha256-1c558d1bce4d72d4b38a622df9ebc7c8158d716f04045519f2a2066bf3a6e171?context=explore). I have found this to also be the case going from 12.1 to 12.2.

Answer (score 4):

postgres has two required environment variables names `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` if you not provide them container will not run.

[gitlab-ci documentation about services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/postgres.html)

Answer (score 0):

Also have same problem, but my case was that I have started new docker inside script block:

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: ${GOOGLE_CLOUD_IMAGE}
  only:
    - merge_requests
  extends: .build-backend
  services:
    - docker:19.03.5-dind
    - postgres:11.1-alpine
  script:
    - docker build -t ${IMAGE_NAME}:${CI_COMMIT_SHA} -f docker/Dockerfile.prod .
    - docker run -t sh -c 'poetry run python manage.py test apps'
```

Problem was that postgres alias was create into script space, not into new docker container space, so I started using postgres inside script and have connected to local network:

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: ${GOOGLE_CLOUD_IMAGE}
  only:
    - merge_requests
  extends: .build-backend
  services:
    - docker:19.03.5-dind
  script:
    - docker network create my-net
    - docker run -d --network my-net --name postgres postgres:11.1-alpine 
    - docker build -t ${IMAGE_NAME}:${CI_COMMIT_SHA} -f docker/Dockerfile.prod .
    - docker run -t --network my-net sh -c 'poetry run python manage.py test apps'
```